# Grouping Sets, Roll-up but with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rollup

I have a query that produces the following results. The problem I'm having is how can I create 3 rows at the bottom showing the totals for >=14 days, and 1-13 days followed by an overall total.

```
select
[Period],
[Person],
count(*) as NumberOfRecords,
sum([Amount]) as [Amount]
```

If I do the below and exclude the Person I get an overall total, but I need the Person to show also:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(([[Period]),());
```

How could this be done?

[image]

```
Create table #temp
(
    Period varchar(50),
    Person varchar(100),
    NumberOfRecords int,
    Amount money
)

insert into #temp
(
    Period,
    Person,
    NumberOfRecords,
    Amount
)
select
    '>= 14 days','',3,100
union all
select
    '>= 14 days','John Smith',32,200
union all
select
    '>= 14 days','Joe Bloggs',50,400
union all
select
    '>= 14 days','Jane Doe',52,750
union all
select
    '>= 14 days','Barry Knight',46,1000
union all
select
    '1-13 days','Bob the Builder',331,7500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROLLUP` for subtotals.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(Period) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE Period END Period, 
    Person, SUM(NumberOfRecords) NumberOfRecords, 
    SUM(Amount) Amount 
from #temp
GROUP BY ROLLUP ((Period),(Period, Person))
ORDER BY GROUPING(Period), GROUPING(Person)
```

Result:

```
Period               Person               NumberOfRecords Amount
-------------------- -------------------- --------------- ---------------------
>= 14 days                                3               100.00
>= 14 days           Barry Knight         46              1000.00
>= 14 days           Jane Doe             52              750.00
>= 14 days           Joe Bloggs           50              400.00
>= 14 days           John Smith           32              200.00
1-13 days            Bob the Builder      331             7500.00
1-13 days            NULL                 331             7500.00
>= 14 days           NULL                 183             2450.00
Total                NULL                 514             9950.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use `ROLLUP`, I'm a fan of `GROUPING SETS`:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( (Period, Person), (Period), () );
```